# Why does my PUT request fail CORS only when sending without headers and in Chrome

Tags: javascript, spring, google-chrome, spring-mvc, angular

I have an Angular2 service making calls to a Java Spring controller, which up until Aug 16 was working fine. It makes PUT, POST, DELETE, and GET requests to the resource. The issue is that the preflight request for PUT calls is now coming back 403 forbidden, and this issue has only sprung up for PUT requests, only on chrome (I am using the most current version I believe, 52.0.2173.116), and only when I make my PUT request without attaching any headers.

Angular2 Typescript put & delete calls look as follows:

```
let body = JSON.stringify({sequence_number: 1, task_id: 43});
http.put('http://localhost:8080/item/ae84k38d', body);

http.delete('http://localhost:8080/item/id38dk42');
```

CorsMapping in WebMVCConfig in Spring code:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE");
}
```

Those put/delete calls result in the following preflight OPTIONS requests & responses according to Fiddler
[DELETE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHYbj.png), [PUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Objy0.png)

One thing to note, which I'm not entirely sure the significance of, is that Fiddler shows that Chrome tagged on a Access-Control-Request-Headers header, without any values, whereas the same request from FireFox ommitted this header on the preflight request.

What's interesting is that, if I then go and change the put request to:

```
http.put('http://localhost:8080/item/ae84k38d', body, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application-json');
```

and append the following to the CORS mapping:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE")
            .allowedHeaders("content-type");
}
```

then the put requests will once again succeed in chrome, which is why I say this only happens when I don't supply headers on my PUT call.

I guess my question is, does anybody have an idea of why this is happening? Am I using the CorsRegistry incorrectly in spring? I'm at a bit of a loss as to where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Found https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication/issues/111

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thank you for that, that was incredibly helpful. I dug into how Spring handles the preflight OPTIONS requests, and saw a similar issue as described in the link you provided in Springs DefaultCorsProcessor class, in terms of rejecting a preflight request due to an empty Access-Control-Request-Headers header (at least on the Spring version i'm using, 4.2.5) Again, thanks for the link, that was just what I needed to get me on the right track.